# How to access an external website which has access control by using PHP file_get_contents()

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I’m trying to build PHP code to access an external website.
The website has access control so I tried to post ‘User ID’ and ‘Password’ by using ‘file_get_contents()’ method as below.

```
<?php

$data = array(  
"name attrib of User ID" => " USER ID ",
"name attrib of Password " => "PASSWORD"
);
$data = http_build_query($data, "", "&");

$header = array(
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($data),
"User-Agent: ‘proper User agent’"
);

$context = array(
"http" => array(
"method"  => "POST",
"header"  => implode("\r\n", $header),
"content" => $data
)
);

$url = "URL where the access authentification is done";
echo file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($context));

?>
```

I expected to see the content which is for ‘after login’.
But the result was content for ‘before login’.

The fact that the target is an external website makes it difficult for me to figure out the cause since I don’t know what code is there in the target server.
I presume that redirect to login page might occur due to failure of login attempt.
The environment is local server installed apache with PHP5.
If you have any idea why the code doesn’t work, please tell me the reason and I’d highly appreciate it.

Just for information, code below which is implemented with form tags and javascript definitely works and I can log in automatically.
Note that the URL after login is different from the one where the access authentification is done.
Apparently, redirect occurs when authorized.

```
<form action=" URL where the access authentification is done " method="post">
<input value="USER ID" name="LoginForm[username]" type="text" />
<input value="PASSWORD" name="LoginForm[password]" />       
<button id="submitForm">
</button>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("submitForm").click();
</script>
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Might want to consider using CURL instead. it's a lot more precise for this kind of job